# Translation, Scaling and Rotation of Matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Two 2D house models A and B are shown in the figure below. House A has one point at (3,2) and House B has one point at (0,-1).

Calculate a chain of matrices that, when post-multiplied by the vertices of House A, will
transform all the vertices of House A into the vertices of House B, i.e. translate and
rotate the house point (3,2) to (0,-1). The transformation must also scale the size of
House A by half to House B.

[image]

**My Attempt**

First we need to move House A to the origin so we use the translation matrix.

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & -3 \\
        0 & 1 & -2 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Then we have to scale it down by half as per the requirement in the question.

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Then I rotate it clockwise

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Then I translate it from the origin to the House B

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Finally I multiply all of these matrices together with our original matrix

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        3 \\
        2 \\
        1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

The only problem is, I don't get (0,-1). Instead I get (1,-1.5) which leads me to believe I have done something wrong. I have used a matrix calculator so I know my math is correct so one or more of my matrices are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the homogeneous coordinates that you wrote the matrices for, the tip of House A is represented by $(3,2,1)$, not $(3,2,0)$. If you use that, you get $(0,-1,1)$ as expected.

Comment: Whoops, missed that. I checked my calculations again but still the answer is not coming out as expected.

Comment: @Aceboy1993: The first multiplication yields $(0,0,1)$, and that remains invariant until the last multiplication transforms it into $(0,-1,1)$.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but the first multiplication I did was Translation x Scale which yields a 3x3 matrix not (0,0,1)

Comment: @Aceboy1993: I see -- I was multiplying the vector with the matrices one by one. Then it sounds like the problem is that you're multiplying the matrices in the wrong order. Translation is applied first, then scaling, so if you form the product of the matrices, you need the scaling matrix times the translation matrix, not the other way around.

Comment: The order I multiplied it was - Scale * TranslationToOrigin * Rotation * TranslationToHouseB * H. Where H is the original point of House A. Yet this still gives me the wrong answer. Is the order correct?

Comment: @Aceboy1993: No, that's not even in reverse order, that's completely jumbled. You wrote them down in the right order in the question; just multiply them in that order, keeping in mind that the right-most factor is applied to $H$ first and the left-most factor is applied last.

Comment: Ok, I've done it in that order and now I'm getting (-5/2, -7/2, 1).

Comment: @Aceboy1993: That's what you get when you multiply them in reverse order. As I said, "keeping in mind that the right-most factor is applied to $H$ first and the left-most factor is applied last".

Comment: When you say right-most factor is applied to H first, do you mean the translation(0,-1)?

Comment: @Aceboy1993: No, I mean quite generally that if you have some product of matrices $ABC$ and you apply it to a vector $v$, i.e. $ABCv$, then this is $A(B(Cv))$, so you're applying first $C$, then $B$, then $A$. So if you want the translation through $(-3,-2)$ to be applied first to the coordinates $(3,2,1)$ of the tip of the house, as you correctly stated in the question, then that has to be the right-most factor in the product of the matrices.

Comment: Ok perfect, I managed to get the answer!!! The order like you said was the issue. Thanks for the patience. Much appreciated!

Comment: Just a quick question, in this scenario and in all scenarios like this, is it not pointless to calculate anything other than the first translation to the origin and then the translation back or to another point since rotating and scaling will always yield a result (0,0,1)?

Comment: @Aceboy1993: No, that's only true for the tip of the house that you're using to construct the transformation. The question asked to "Calculate a chain of matrices that, when post-multiplied by the vertices of House $A$, will transform all the vertices of House $A$ into the vertices of House $B$". The other vertices don't get translated to the origin, so the rotation and the scaling do matter for them. The transformation transforms the entire House $A$ into the entire House $B$, which is obviously scaled and rotated compared to House $A$.

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense!